# Using Lambda to query collection / joined table

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda 'where' query, querying an Order table like this:

```
List<Order> returnedOrders = _session.Query<Script>()Where(s => s.orderId == orderIdParam).ToList();
```

I want to also check the value of a column in the related `OrderDetails` table. So `returnedOrders` has a collection of `OrderDetails`, i.e. `returnedOrders.orderDetails`

So the SQL query would look something like:

```
Where OrderId = 12345 and Order.OrderDetail.CreatedDate = '01-Jan-2013'
```

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logical AND (`&&`) inside the `Where` method:

```
var date = new Date(2013,1,1);

List<Order> returnedOrders = 
    _session.Query<Script>()
            .Where(s => 
                s.orderId == orderIdParam && 
                s.OrderDetails.Any(d => d.CreatedDate == date))
            .ToList();
```

You can alternatively append another `Where` method.

```
var date = new Date(2013,1,1);

List<Order> returnedOrders = 
    _session.Query<Script>()
            .Where(s => s.orderId == orderIdParam)
            .Where(s => s.OrderDetails.Any(d => d.CreatedDate == date))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: That's what I thought but I don't get the column names of orderdetails in intellisense. s.Orderdetails is an IList it that helps, so I get list operations like s.Orderdetails.Remove,  s.Orderdetails.First, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know Id of order it seems useless but something like this

```
from order in orders 
from detail in order.Details 
where 
    order.Id = orderId && 
    order.Id == detail.OrderId && 
    detail.CreateDate == createDate
select order
```